# Why are some images cropped in pdfs?

Tags: image, pdf, itext, cut, itext7

Itextpdf crops some images when they are added to a Pdf document.

I have written a demo showing the problem (https://github.com/buda-base/buda-iiif-server/blob/master/src/test/java/io/bdrc/iiif/PDFBugDemo.java) using the following [pom](https://github.com/buda-base/buda-iiif-server/blob/master/pom.xml) and the this image: (https://github.com/buda-base/buda-iiif-server/blob/master/src/test/resources/test.tif)

The demo code produces two different files from the same image using itext7 and Apache PdfBox. The expected output is that which is produced by PdfBox. Itext7 obviously crops the original image. This doesn't occur all the times and I suspect a specific issue with tif files.

Files are here for Itext7 (https://drive.google.com/open?id=16oUhSnhbW4QWiYn2aFPsKp3xA0__yd3B) and for the pdfBox(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1My_-EM27VARKDBgM5tMig7FkYlTWtflG)

Comment: I suspect that itext has some top/left margin settings because it is higher level, unlike pdfbox. Looking at the content streams, itext has "2009 0 0 344.65 36 -23.65 cm" and pdfbox has "2081 0 0 357 0 0 cm" as transform. The last two numbers are the translation (x y move), the two other non 0 numbers are x y scales. Have a look at the margin methods of document in itext, maybe this helps: https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/7.0.0/com/itextpdf/layout/Document.html

Comment: Setting all the document margins to zero solved the issue ! It would be great to have these settings as the default settings. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please answer the question yourself with the code you used (I don't use itext much, it was just a guess and then I looked at the javadoc). Re default, I assume that itext has a default configuration to look "nice", thus the margins. It makes a lot of sense for texts, so it also makes sense for images.

Comment: Indeed, adding content via the iText `Document` means asking iText to layout the content automatically with margins (which might be filled with headers and footers) etc. For an actual pendant of the PDFBox code you'd have used the `writer.getDirectContent` and its more low-level methods. There the margins don't interfere.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact the issue is coming from PDFDocument default margins values. Thanks to Tilman Hausherr I was able to solve the problem by doing the following, before adding the images to the doc/page :

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("testPdfItext.pdf", new WriterProperties().setPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_2_0));
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
        document.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```